# Python - How to set files to list of tuples

Tags: python, flask

Im new to python. How to set files to list of tuples in following format?

```
multiple_files = [
     ('file', ('foo.png', file.read())),
     ('file', ('bar.png', file.read())]
```

Python code:

```
from flask import request
multiple_files = []
inspect_files = request.files.getlist('file')
print(inspect_files) # [<FileStorage: 'foo.png' ('image/png')>, <FileStorage: 'bar.png' ('image/png')>]
for file in inspect_files:
    #What is the logic to set files from inspect_files to list of tuples and push it into multiples_files?
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use the `append` method?

Comment: it looks like nested tuples which makes me confused

Comment: You can append a nested tuple like `multiple_files.append(('file', ('foo.png', some_data)))`. Is that what you were asking for, or do you not know how to get `some_data` given `'foo.png'`? Or do you not know how to get `'foo.png'` given `<FileStorage: 'foo.png' ('image/png')>`?

Comment: What purpose does the fixed string `'file'` serve? Would a simple list of name/content pairs suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Before print add:

```
multiple_files.push(inspect_files)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to have correct code formatting. See [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information.